# Get Ledger Report Mysql Table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have inserting mysql table

**this my table**

```
ID |VoucherNO|   VoucherType|   AccName         |   Particulars       |   Debit     |    Credit |     Date
---|---------|--------------|-------------------|---------------------|-------------|-----------|------------
1  |    1    |  Cash Payment|    OFFICE EXPENSE |   CASH ACCOUNT      |     500     |     0 | 2018-nov-25 
---|---------|--------------|-------------------|---------------------|-------------|-----------|------------
2  |    1    |  Cash Payment|    CASH ACCOUNT   |   OFFICE EXPENSE    |     0       |     500   | 2018-nov-25 
---|---------|--------------|-------------------|---------------------|-------------|-----------|------------
3  |    2    |  Cash Payment|    OFFICE EXPENSE |   CASH ACCOUNT      |     250     |     0 | 2018-nov-26 
---|---------|--------------|-------------------|---------------------|-------------|-----------|------------
4  |    2    |  Cash Payment|    CASH ACCOUNT   |   OFFICE EXPENSE    |     0       |     250   | 2018-nov-26 
---|---------|--------------|-------------------|---------------------|-------------|-----------|-----------
5  |    3    |  Cash Payment|    OFFICE EXPENSE |   CASH ACCOUNT      |     100     |     0 | 2018-nov-27 
---|---------|--------------|-------------------|---------------------|-------------|-----------|------------
6  |    3    |  Cash Payment|    CASH ACCOUNT   |   OFFICE EXPENSE    |     0       |     100   | 2018-nov-27 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and i want fetch report mysql table like this

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---
Date         | VoucherNo |    VoucherType   | Partuclars    | debit  |   credit   |  Balance
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2018-nov-25      1          Cash Payment     CASH ACCOUNT   500                      500
___________________________________________________________________________________________
2018-nov-26      2          Cash Payment     CASH ACCOUNT   250                      750                
___________________________________________________________________________________________
2018-nov-27      3          Cash Payment     CASH ACCOUNT   100                      850
____________________________________________________________________________________________

                            total                          850            0.00      850
```

This table received me from the Inventory Software ,but I don't Know Report Query
How will this be done with the PHP and MYSQL

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: this is a specification and not a question

Comment: If you want to pass you gotta go to class. Don't skip and then dump homework problems here. You are expected to make an effort. Also see [How do I ask homework questions on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+ask+homework+questions+on+Stack+Overflow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP is probably going to have to do most of the work, so I am going to omit the SQL, but I am assuming a simple `SELECT * FROM myTableName ORDER BY VoucherNo;` would work (tjhe ORDER BY may not be needed if that is the primary key).  I am also using 0 as a starting balance, so adjust that if you need to.

```
$balance = 0;
$curdate = '';
$output = array();
$curValue = array(
    'Date' => '',
    'VoucherNo' => 0, 
    'VoucherType' => '', 
    'Partuclars' => '', 
    'debit' => 0, 
    'credit' => 0, 
    'Balance' => 0
);

foreach($prePopulatedResultsArray as $row) {

    // if the current day is done being populated, add data to output and reset current
    if ($curdate !== $row['Date']) {
    // only add the current value if it has been populated
        if ($curdate !== '')
            $output[] = $curValue;

        $curValue = array(
            'Date' => $row['Date'], 
            'VoucherNo' => $row['VoucherNo'], 
            'VoucherType' => $row['VoucherType'], 
            'Partuclars' => $row['Partuclars'], 
            'debit' => $row['debit'], 
            'credit' => $row['credit'], 
            'Balance' => $balance + $row['debit']
        );
        $curdate = $row['Date'];

    // if it is still the same day as the last iteration, add to existing values
    } else {
        $curValue['debit'] = $curValue['debit']+$row['debit'];
        $curValue['credit'] = $curValue['debit']+$row['credit'];
        $balance = $balance + $row['debit'];
        $curValue['Balance'] = $curValue['Balance']+$balance;
    }
}
```

This may be a little off from what you were aiming for because I am basing your output on the fact that you are adding `debit` to `Balance` and I am populating `credit`, even though you had empty values in your expected results.  Let me know if the answer needs adjusting.